# Why this snippet is giving me compilation error

Tags: c++, output, cout, ostream

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostream os=cout;
    os<<"ABC";

}
```

This is giving me compilation error.

Comment: Have you tried `ostream& os = cout;`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you think your question is trivial enough that you don't have to copy the error, why are you asking in first place?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostream& os = cout;
    os << "ABC"<< endl;

}
```

`ostream& os = cout;` declares a reference to `cout` called `os`.

Answer (score 1):

You will surely get an error as you cannot directly assign it to count... You will need to link it with the reference of ostream...

Can you change the line:

> ostream os=cout;

to

> ostream & os = cout

Hope it help you then...

Comment: It's ok @Nitin, I hope you have solved the error now... Let me know if you need any more help with understand any concepts...